# Passing messages from Node.js to external systems?

Tags: node.js, nservicebus, cqrs, message-bus

I'm completely new to Node.JS, if I want to pass messages to external systems using a message/event/servicebus.. what alternatives are there that integrates well with Node?

The messages are just JSON strings, and external systems can be whatever, e.g. a C# agent or some such.

(Maybe this should be on some other part of the site cluser than stackoverflow since it's more of a tech question than programming)?

Comment: Try to be more specific about what you want to pass messages to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I built a proof of concept for gameinformer.com's commenting system with nodejs/mogodb as the comment service, sending messages to RabitMQ (with node-amqp) and HornetQ (with stomp). A message bus is definitely the way to go if you're building enterprise level applications. I haven't tried sending messages from nodejs to MSMQ but when I do, my first attempt will be with the node js stomp module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like Zeromq, redis or you can use a transport protocol like TCP or HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You are not very specific.  But Node.js gives you several options.  And you could always use one of these, if you want to implement something yourself:

http://nodejs.org/api/net.html

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Answer (score 0):

IMHO I would suggest to use a message broker. You may use [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org) with node.JS through [Stomp](http://stomp.github.com/) ([node.js plugin](https://github.com/kates/node-stomp)). I have implement such architecture and has serve me well for JSON-body-messages ( average 6k TPS ). Both ActiveMQ and Stomp are lightweight enough and easy to serve your application's logic and scalability.

If you can't/don't want to use an external message broker you may use only the Stomp as it provides API for any of the most used technologies (from php to C#,Java & C++). (with activeMQ you could also use JS client through [Websocket](http://activemq.apache.org/websockets.html) & [Ajax](http://activemq.apache.org/ajax.html))

Cheers!